# make 403 forbidden for folders that have not index page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a webserver and I need to create a 403 forbidden for all folders ( include sub folders) that do not have any index file , I know I can do it with .htaccess , but as far as I know It only used for main folder , not sub folders . how can I block accessing website folders that do not have index file ?

thanks

Comment: Turn off `Options Indexes` in your config. http://serverfault.com/questions/252603/disabled-apache-directory-indexing-not-applied-recursively-is-my-config-or-unde

Comment: yes , also I found a link here : http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/ , but thanks Jonathon , your link is useful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with `DirectoryIndex on` this rule should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ - [F]
```

Comment: I found this link useful for disabling DirectoryIndex: http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/